# in (a) good/perfect/bad condition

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I am interested in the article usage in this specific expression. I see that sometimes *'a'* and sometimes the *zero article* is used. The zero article seems to prevail, though.

Is the article simply optional or are there some kind of restrictions on when you can use it?

[The Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/condition):

> The driver was taken to the hospital where he was reported to be *in
> **(a)** good/stable/critical condition*.

[The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/condition):

> a used car *in perfect condition*
>
> The house is in ***a** generally poor condition*.

Comment: I think the difference is made from the adverb that is present in one sentence and missing in the other one.

Comment: Well, I can find lots of examples on google books where the phrase "in a poor condition" is used without any adverbs, e.g. _Some flood defences remain in a poor condition_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on whether the speaker considers *good* (or *stable, critical,* or *mint*) to be an adjective describing *condition*, or the two-word phrase *x condition* to be an [adjective phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) describing the object. In the former case, an article would be included; in the latter, it is omitted, even though a hyphen isn't being used:

> John had a mint-condition 1954 Chevrolet.

So, even though your question asks about the article, it would be related to a question inquiring about the hyphen. In this case, I can find instances of both in print literature:

> A mint condition card is flawless, with no nicks, cuts, stains, creases, scratches, or offcentering. (*Collecting Basketball Cards: A Complete Guide with Prices,* 2000)
>
> A mint-condition baseball signed by Babe Ruth and Lou Gehrig sold at auction last year for more than $68,000. (*Kiplinger's Personal Finance,* Mar 2000)

If you're interested, you can read more about the very-vexing hyphenation convention problem at [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word).

Comment: So is the short answer, the article is optional? Because as seen from the examples I provided, this phrase can often  be viewed as both adjective + noun and two-word phrase at the same time, without much difference in the actual meaning.

Comment: I think that's the short answer, yes.